# SQL Server modifying XML columns with unique value for all the rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a xml column, I need to modify a few fields in the XML for every row. The new values should be unique to that entry, I want to do that by appending the primary key (ID int) to the value in the fields.

For instance: I inserted the rows into a temp table. For simplicity, assume the table only has two columns: `payload (XML), id (INT, primary key)`

```
UPDATE #Temp
SET payloadXml.modify('replace value of (/abc/customer/contact/name[@part=("first")]/text())[1] with "hello"')
FROM #Temp
```

This will replace the first name field with hello. But I want to append the id of that row to this field. I tried `sql:variable`, but to no avail. Is this even possible?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: For appending, you probably want `insert ... after ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sql:column` to reference a relational column in your XML DML, eg

```
drop table if exists #temp
go
create table #temp(id int identity primary key, payloadXML xml)
go
insert into #temp(payloadXml) values ('<abc><customer><contact><name part="first">foo</name></contact></customer></abc>');
insert into #temp(payloadXml) values ('<abc><customer><contact><name part="first">foo</name></contact></customer></abc>');
insert into #temp(payloadXml) values ('<abc><customer><contact><name part="first">foo</name></contact></customer></abc>');

WITH q as 
(
 select *, concat('hello ', id) new_name 
 from #Temp
)
UPDATE q
SET payloadXml.modify('replace value of (/abc/customer/contact/name[@part=("first")]/text())[1] 
                       with sql:column("new_name")')

select payloadXML from #temp
```